# jquery ajax dont works - succes and error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

PHP code works, but function success and error dont work.

```
$('#block-button-send').click(function() {                                  
    $.ajax({
        url: 'code.php',
        data: {mail: $('#block-email').val(), blok: "Název", name: $('#block-name').val(), tel: $('#block-tel').val()},
        success: function() {
            $('#block-message').appendTo('Zpráva odeslána').addClass('good').slideUp();
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#block-message').appendTo('Zpráva neodeslána').addClass('bad').slideUp();
        }
    }); 
});
```

thank you

Comment: What says the javascript console?

Comment: where i can found javascript console, i dont use it

Comment: On the most browser with the Keyboard-Shortcuts `CMD + SHIFT + i`, `12` and under Mac OS-X with `CMD + ALT + i`. Otherwise over the Menu (Extras > Tools,..)

Comment: Show the relevant HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is relevatnt HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you don't state what the exact problem is, you are using the wrong function: `appendTo` tries to append `$('#block-message')` to the `Zpráva neodeslána` element (which does not exist).

You need something like the `append()`, `text()` or `html()` functions instead.

For example:

```
$('#block-message').text('Zpráva odeslána').addClass('good').slideUp();
```

Comment: with this, text is added to div, but animation dont works

Comment: @popy So add an html element and animate that.

Comment: i dont understand you what i should to do

Comment: only animation (slideUp) dont work, but adding clas to element and adding text works

Comment: @popy `slideUp()` hides the element, if you want to show it, you need `slideDown()`.

Comment: you are right, i overlooked it

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at jQuery's documentation for append() and appendTo(), you'll see that appendTo works in the opposite order that you're using it:

`$( "Zpráva odeslána" ).appendTo( "#block-message" ).addClass('good').slideUp();`

Here's the documentation: [jquery appendTo()](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Is how it should look for your example, because you're taking the text and appending it TO the element.

When it doubt, say it out (loud).  Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry about that.  Here's a very basic example. http://jsfiddle.net/yHWYL/ I separated the appendTo and the slideDown (as @jeroen mentioned) to make it a bit more apparent what's going on.

Comment: if you do it on 2 rows then its ok, but i dont tryied, so there is why it why it dont work

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that in my example, I added a <p> tag to the text.  appendTo will only append elements.  @jeroen's answer uses .text() which is the correct approach.